# calculating correct answers and displaying total score in AngularJS quiz

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm building a quiz application in AngularJS but I do not know how to iterate over the questions to add and display the correct answers.

Please help I am new to programming.

The quiz in JSON format as shown below:

```
"questions": [{
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "In a village, the number of people infected with HIV in 2001 was 100. In 2004, 250 people were infected. Find the ratio of those infected in 2001 to those infected in 2004.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 1:5", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 2:5", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 3:5", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 5:1", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 5:2", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "The ratio of the length to the breadth of a room is 7:5. Find the length of the room if the breadth is 10m.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 10m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 12m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 14m", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 21m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 35m", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Increase 80 by 10%.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 8m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 10m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 80m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 88m", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 108m", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Odiri bought 12 cartons of biscuits for N3,000.00. Find the cost of 7.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. ₦250.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. ₦442.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. ₦840.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. ₦1,750.00", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. ₦2,700.00", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to look at converting the JSON into an object using `JSON.parse()`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Once in an object you could then loop through it using `ng-repeat`

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 0):

here is a poc : 
[check answers thanks to radio buttons and show correct/false thanks to ng-if](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angularjs-flvegp)
**you must check the docs/do a tutorial in order to improve your skills
Maybe next time send a first work on a platform like stackblitz for example.**

Answer (score 0):

hie i had crack at it please view the code pen

https://codepen.io/thefallen78/pen/ZPOgKL

```js
    (function () {
 'use strict';

 angular.module("myapp",[]).controller("helloController", function($scope){
 

   $scope.quiz = {"questions": [{
        "Id": 5,
        "Name": "In a village, the number of people infected with HIV in 2001 was 100. In 2004, 250 people were infected. Find the ratio of those infected in 2001 to those infected in 2004.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 1:5", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 2:5", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 3:5", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 5:1", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 5:2", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 6,
        "Name": "The ratio of the length to the breadth of a room is 7:5. Find the length of the room if the breadth is 10m.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 10m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 12m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 14m", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 21m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 35m", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 7,
        "Name": "Increase 80 by 10%.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. 8m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. 10m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. 80m", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. 88m", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. 108m", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    },
    {
        "Id": 8,
        "Name": "Odiri bought 12 cartons of biscuits for N3,000.00. Find the cost of 7.",
        "QuestionTypeId": 1,
        "Options": [
            { "Id": 1, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "A. ₦250.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 2, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "B. ₦442.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 3, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "C. ₦840.00", "Answer": false },
            { "Id": 4, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "D. ₦1,750.00", "Answer": true },
            { "Id": 5, "QuestionId": 1, "Name": "E. ₦2,700.00", "Answer": false }],
        "QuestionType": { "Id": 1, "Name": "Multiple Choice", "Active": true }
    }]}

});
  
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">

  <title>the quiz</title>


  </head>

<body ng-app = "myapp">
  
  <div class = "container">
    <div class = "row" ng-controller = "helloController">
      <div class = "col-md-6 col-md-offset-3" style = "background-color:red;">
        <form action = "POST" ng-repeat = "(key,value) in quiz">
          <label>{{key}}</label>
          <div class = "form-group" ng-repeat = "item in value">   
            <label>{{item.Name}}</label>
          <select class = "form-control" >
            <option ng-repeat = "options in item.Options">{{options.Name}}</option>
            
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
       
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, what i'm asking for is "how to sum up all correct answers and display total score